# Can i prevent global admins or other sharepoint admins from accessing our site collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration

We have been working on a new sharepoint office 365 project. where our customer have already added a single site collection inside the root url. and we have created 5 site collections and grant users the related permissions (Read or Contribute). but i have this concern regarding office 365 permission:-

Now how i can prevent the global admin or other sharepoint admins from accessing our site collections? as our customer have send us the username which we used to create site collections. which means that our customer already have a global admin and maybe other sharepoint admins. and these admins can access our site collections and do some customizations (by mistake), regardless of the permision we grant inside the site collections security groups.

so can i restrict accessing our site collections to only users we have granted them inside the security groups? currently on all the site collections i grant users/group-of-users either Read or Contribute. and i grant our admin full control. but the only concern is if there are other admins defined inside office 365 , then these admins can do everything they want. so can i restrict this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prevent SharePoint or Global Admins from gaining access to a Site Collection.

Comment: so you mean if our customer have defined or will define sharepoint admins inside office 365 then these admin can access our site collection with full permissions??for example when our customer send us the sharepoint admin username, i was able to access the site collection they have , and i had full control on the site collection... so we can not prevent this?

Comment: That's correct. While Global/SharePoint Admins do not have access by default, they can grant themselves access at any time.

Comment: but in my case they send us a new username which have permsion to create/delete site collections (i think the username was office 365 admin) and using this username i was able to access the site collection they have been working on and i have full control over the site, although i did not grant my self and permission..

Comment: It doesn't really matter either way. They can grant themselves access where needed. This is the point of administration. If you don't trust your admins, that's an HR problem, not a technology one.

Comment: yes i got ur point and totally agree with you.. i mean when i check my username permission on their site collection i can see that i have every possible permission on the site collection but not through any security group. which means since i am SP admin or office 365 admin i can do everything ..

Comment: John, I'm not sure what you're expecting here. If they're an admin, they're an admin and can do anything they want. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: my question was if we can prevent other SP admins from accessing the sites with full permission, and u answered this question. but what i am saying that by defualt any admin will have full permission on the sites without the need to grant them-self permissions...

Comment: They don't have full permissions by default, it just isn't granted on the site level.  In central administration in SharePoint, you can also grant permissions on a web application level.  That is likely where it is done.  Administrators are usually called upon to help with site issues, and it would be tedious and unproductive if they have to be given permissions each time they need to access a site.  So you do it once at the web application level instead.

Comment: That's not true as this question is for SharePoint Online, not on-prem.

Comment: @DubStep now even inside on-premise we have managed accounts. now if i access the sites using a managed account inside on-premise,i will be logged-in as system admin ... and i will have full permission on every thing, without having to explicitly assign the managed accounts to the sites

Comment: @johnG That's because managed accounts have permissions assigned during setup of such an account, set at the web application level.  You shouldn't login with managed accounts though.

Comment: @TrevorSeward What's not true?  They do have full permissions by default in SharePoint Online?